# Fetching random column value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Suppose I have a table product_details with 10 distinct products in it.1st column is product_ID which is primary key.

Now I want to insert 90 random  entries into order_details which has a column product_ID which is referencing product_details.product_ID

How will I generate 100 random entries out of given 10 entries in other table in oracle.

Pl tell me SQL query for this problem (not the procedure).

Comment: Procedures is just a series of SQL statements placed in a method. However, if you dislike procedure, it is still possible to achieve what you want. You will need to use for loop in the sql query to achieve what you want. there are built-in random functions in sql too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have 10 rows then there shouldn't be any performance issues with just doing a `cross join`, ordering by `dbms_random.value` and filtering to the first 90 rows (as part of an insert statement):

```
insert into order_details
select *
from(
select p1.*
from product_details p1
cross join product_details p2
order by dbms_random.value
) where rownum <= 90;
```

**Fiddle demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d390c/1/0

I assume you have other columns than just `product_id`, so modify accordingly.

If the table were much larger than 10 rows, and you still only wanted 90 at random, you could use `sample()` to reduce it to a little over your target of 90 rows, then order by `dbms_random.value` afterward, where rownum <= 90. Doing so would have a greater performance improvement the larger the dataset. With 10 rows it would be negligible. The full cross product is only 100 rows.

Comment: Thanks for help.
Actually it is possible to generate 100 values by cross join because in example 100 = 10*10(lucky example).
But what if I need to generate 83457 rows rather than just 100 rows.

Comment: You could use 4 cross joins (100,000) where rownum <= 83457. Also if the product id #s are numeric and are between 1 and X you could and probably should use `connect by` instead. The approach I posted has the advantage of working for any product IDs though.